# Drupal 7 - Wanting content (of certain content-type) to appear in block

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have recently started on Drupal (v 7) to create a small company website.

After much reading and watching tutorials, I have started to create my new theme from scratch. I have defined **regions** and customised the **page.tpl.php** file to place them into the template (and **node.tpl.php** etc). All these changes are working and the layout is looking good, and any item I add appears in the main content output.

In my footer region, I have created a **block** in which I would like links to appear. I have also created a **content-type** called footer links (with relevant fields) and I have created a couple items of content for it.

The block is showing fine (the title and block body appear). However, despite scouring the documentation, I am not sure what needs to be done to make the items of content (footer links) appear in this block.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

**info file snippet for a region**

```
regions[footer_one] = Footer Column One
```

**... and code in page.tpl.php**

```
    <div class="one">
          <?php if ($page['footer_one']): ?>
            <?php print render($page['footer_one']); ?>
          <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views is really powerful and sounds like it will do exactly what you need. Otherwise, you can create a menu for your items and place that menu in your region as well.

Regarding your original code, you'd probably need to grab the information about the nodes from the database in order to construct a list on your own, but views basically does that for you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you just need simple footer links, no need to create a content type for this, you can simple create a menu and add a menu block in footer.

If you really want to use your own content type for these links, you can create a view (with views module) to display what you want in a block.

About creating a theme from scratch, did you try before to create a [sub theme](http://drupal.org/node/225125) ?

PS: I don't think drupal is a good cms for "small company website".

Comment: Hi Soju, Thanks for your advice - much appreciated. I will have a go with the views module. I will need it to implement other regions, but you're right - I should use a menu block instead for these footer links. Re the choice of Drupal... I know it is like using a sledge hammer to crack a nut, but I need to get to grips with Drupal and am starting smaller!